# How to set hyperlink color for an individual link?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I am writing a very simple HTML page for selecting among a few files. The linked-to files are the *current* an *past* versions of some data file.

I want the "current" link to be in blue and the "past" links to be in light-blue. This is easily achievable through setting of the `font color` property in the `<A ..>` tag.

However, doing so means the color of visited links is not changed to purple.

An alternative is to use `link`, `vlink` and `alink` properties in the `<body ...>` tag, as explained [here](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks02.htm).

But doing so means that all links look the same. Apparently, the `link`, `vlink` and `alink` properties do not work when put in the `<A ...>` tag context.

**How can I set a different "visited link" color per link?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `a:visited` selector for that:

```
<html>
    <style>
        a.past:visited {
            color: light-blue;
        }

        a.current:visited {
            color: blue;
        }
     </style>
     <body>
         <a class="current" href="#">Link</a>
         <a class="past" href="#">Link</a>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. An HTML noob here, where do you put those?

Comment: its CSS, you put it in the `<style>` tags in your `<head>`

Comment: I tried adding a `<style> suggested code </style>` tag with the code above to the `<head>` and to the `<body>` tags, but there is no apparent difference (used green color, just to make sure).

Comment: @ysap Do you have `past` and `current` classes added to links?

Comment: Just noticed that... apparently no. Don't have any classes. It is a plain straight forward HTML.

Comment: How'd you add those classes?

Comment: OK, looks I found out. In the `<A ...>` tag I added `class="current" `.

Comment: @ysap Updated answer with full HTML page